# Extract only words containing ASCII characters from vector of strings

Tags: r, stringr, qdap

I'm stuck with it, so, please, any advice is welcome.

```
b <- str_extract_all(c('hello ringпрг','trust'), regex("[a-z]+", TRUE))
```

Returns a list:

```
    List of 2
 $ : chr [1:2] "hello" "ring"
 $ : chr "trust"
```

But I want to have a vector with strings of this words for each element of vector `c('hello ringпрг','trust')` such as `"hello ring", "trust"`. Any other functions and packages are welcome too.

Comment: There is no way to only extract English words without a dictionary. Now, if you actually want to extract ASCII characters ...

Comment: @Roland you are right, title edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sapply` with `paste` as in:

```
b<-str_extract_all(c('hello ringпрг','trust'), regex("[a-z]+", TRUE))

sapply(b, paste, collapse = " ")

## [1] "hello ring" "trust"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
unlist(str_extract_all(c('hello ringпрг','trust'), regex("[A-Za-z ]+", TRUE)))
#[1] "hello ring" "trust"
```

Or use the pattern as `"[[:ascii:]]+"`